# Soap Webservice XML parsing in IOS

Tags: ios, xml, web-services, soap

I am new to the SOAP XML web service. I initiating soap request and getting response as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:createemailResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:hellowsdl"><return xsi:type="xsd:string”>{“data”:[{“email”:”ex@yahoo.com”,”pid”:”32502”}]}</return></ns1:createemailResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

In this i want to retreive response string from createemailResponse as {“data”:[{“email”:”ex@yahoo.com”,”pid”:”32502”}]}. Please help me...

Comment: Do you have wsdl file for you SOAP services?

Comment: yes i have wsdl file for soap service.

Comment: are you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some third party tools which will create model classes and service calling classes according to your wsdl design. I have followed the tutorial present in following link for one of my application :

http://www.priyaontech.com/2012/10/soap-based-webservices-integration-in-an-ios-app/

By following above tutorial you can avoid lot of code for calling SOAP services. That way your code looks more structured and readable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing link. I'll check the url.